# XML path error out

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the below select query in my sproc:

```
select node1 =
(
    (select innernode1 = 
           (
            select var1 =
            (
                select
                Val     =   'XXX',  
                spec    =   'yyy'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            )
             FOR XML PATH('var1'), TYPE
             )
    ),
    (select innernode1 = 
            (
            select  var2 =
            (
                    select
                    Val     =   'XXX',  
                    spec    =   'yyy'
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            )
            FOR XML PATH('var2'), TYPE
            )
    )
)
```

Desired/Expected XML output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <node1>
      <innernode1>
         <var1>
            <Spec>yyy</Spec>
            <Val>xxx</Val>
         </var1>
      </innernode1>
      <innernode2>
         <var2>
            <Spec>yyy</Spec>
            <Val>xxx</Val>
         </var2>
      </innernode2>
   </node1>
</root>
```

But the select query is throwing 'incorrect syntax near ','.' error and 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Any help will be appreciated greatly!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL server 2014. Edited the question now

Answer (score 2):

This `FOR XML` statement is not valid syntax... 
What are you trying to achieve? Is the data coming from a table?

You want to get a JSON, but you are creating an XML?

A general hint: Might be this is just for sample data, but - if this was real data - you should avoid *name-numbering*. Instead of `innernode1` and `innernode2` both should be just `innernode`, while the 1 and the 2 are either taken from their position or placed as an attribute / value.

My magic crystal ball tells me, that you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
            innernode1 =
            (
                SELECT
                Spec    =   'yyy',
                Val     =   'XXX'  
                FOR XML PATH('var1'), TYPE
            )
            ,innernode2 =
            (
                SELECT
                Spec    =   'yyy',
                Val     =   'XXX'  
                FOR XML PATH('var2'), TYPE
            )
FOR XML PATH('node1'),ROOT('root');
```

The result

```
<root>
  <node1>
    <innernode1>
      <var1>
        <Spec>yyy</Spec>
        <Val>XXX</Val>
      </var1>
    </innernode1>
    <innernode2>
      <var2>
        <Spec>yyy</Spec>
        <Val>XXX</Val>
      </var2>
    </innernode2>
  </node1>
</root>
```

The `FOR JSON` statment ([read here the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)) looks rather similar, but I cannot test it at the moment. This needs SQL-Server-2017+

Comment: I want my sql select to produce XML as mentioned above. I will later convert that XML to JSON

Comment: @Rick Updated my answer. The XML produced is exactly the same as you state it in your question